# How can i get the inserted new id in codeigniter(or php)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

For example, if the table desc is,

```
id int(11) pk auto_increment
content varchar(128)
```

and if i inserted `(null, 'test')` how can i get the inserted new id?

the input 'test' can't be the where condition, because it is not a unique key, it can be duplicated.

Any good idea?

or do i have to redesign the table to insert some unique key for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$this->db->insert_id()` like

```
$this->db->insert(); //Here your insert query
echo "Insert Id is ".$this->db->insert_id();
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

LAST_INSERT_ID is a value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column. It is session specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last insert id, you can try this

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```